# Winrt How to support snappedview when having control with name?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a very simple and basic problem but don't know how to overcome it.
I want to support snappedview and I already supports it, but not fully.

I can't show the controls that has a name.
For example, I have a bing map control (which is not working with binding...). So I need to give it a name and every action to change it in the code behind. Here is the control example:

```
<map:Map x:Name="map"
         Credentials="{StaticResource BingCredentials}"
         Tapped="Map_Tapped"
         Loaded="Map_Loaded">
         <map:Map.Children>
             <map:MapItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PushpinLocalTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding PushpinModel}" />
         </map:Map.Children>
</map:Map>
```

So, I can't show it in more than one view (FullView or SnappedView...). The problem is that if I write it in datatemplate then the name is not accessible in code behind, so all my code doesn't compile.

What can I do? Maybe a usercontrol? If yes, how?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps, this sample hides the map on snapped view. You may change `Visibility` for whatever property you want and `Collapsed` for the desired value. Notice the map is named *CoolMap*, if you use a different name, change it too.

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage
    x:Class="BingMapsApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:BingMapsApp"
    xmlns:map="using:Bing.Maps"
    xmlns:common="using:BingMapsApp.Common"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <map:Map x:Name="CoolMap" Credentials="{StaticResource BingCredentials}">
            <map:Map.Children>
                <map:MapItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PushpinLocalTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding PushpinModel}">
                    <x:String>blah blah blah</x:String>
                </map:MapItemsControl>
            </map:Map.Children>
        </map:Map>

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <!-- Visual states reflect the application's view state -->
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait" />

                <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CoolMap" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>
</common:LayoutAwarePage>
```

Modify any property using `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames`.